# Do I need to apply for a new ESTA if I'm going to the US again?

Tags: esta

I visited New York City, USA on an ESTA at the end of last year and stayed for ten days. I now want to visit for two months from 28th Feb.

Do I need to apply for another ESTA or am I covered by the last one?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the status of your ESTA [here](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) by using just your passport number and personal details if you do not have your original application number.

An ESTA lasts for 2 years from application/confirmation (usually the same day) or until the expiration of your passport, whichever soonest.

Comment: Small addition to what I think is the best answer:  ESTA lasts for 2 years or until the expiration of the passport you used in the ESTA.  If you want to be sure indeed just go to the website and check the expiration date.

Comment: @DiscoFever That is correct. I will add the additional information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be still valid until the expiration. So you can visit for two months if the expiration of your ESTA happens after that.

Caveats for traveling to Iran if you have a European passport. It might cancel your ESTA.

Comment: It won't cancel it, but at the US airport, they may be able to see it and refuse you entry. A Norwegian told me their monitor was in a weird angle, and that they could see his travels to "dangerous" countries on **previous** passports. Fortunately before 2011 though